# OSSec not working on server with multiple IPS

Tags: ossec

I had to add another IP address to our server (eth0:1 192.168.0.100) and all of the sudden ossec client stopped working.

On the client side I'm seeing this:
2014/02/19 02:31:28 ossec-agentd: INFO: Trying to connect to server (server_ip:1514).
2014/02/19 02:31:28 ossec-agentd: INFO: Using IPv4 for: server_ip.
2014/02/19 02:31:49 ossec-agentd(4101): WARN: Waiting for server reply (not started). Tried: 'server_ip'.

How can this be fixed? Most likely I have to specify the source ip or source interface on the client side but I can't figure out where.

Comment: What is the output of `ip route` on your client?

Comment: 10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.10 
10.0.0.0/8 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.100

Comment: Adding a net mask for 10.0.0.100 fixed it. If you can add an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that your network configuration is incorrect. Check `ip route` to make sure you still have a sane route to the server.